# Execute Scripts in /etc/profile.d/ at Startup as Root?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, startup, archlinux

I'm currently using arch linux, and I have a script in /etc/profile.d/ that's successfully running at boot. However, I'm being prompted to enter my password after the first sudo command, and typing my password twice at login is a little annoying. I don't want my account to never ask for a password when executing sudo commands, if possible, just not for this startup script. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is better suited for SuperUser or possibly Serverfault, see: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/31/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/

Comment: Scripts in that location are executed as root, so my question would be, why are you using sudo in the script?  As for password for sudo, check the sudoers file

Comment: @grail that is actually incorrect, as is the accepted answer. The scripts at `/etc/profile.d` are [*sourced*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/291409/154671) (not executed) by the shell, which runs as the currently logged-in user. So, unless the login account is actually `root`, the shell won't be executed as root and nor will its sourced script commands.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

scripts in /etc/profile.d/ directory are executed as root. no need to sudo command in this scripts. but if you want to run a command as another user you should do it like below command.

```
su - user -c 'command'
```

Comment: According to this qestion https://serverfault.com/questions/1017577/profile-d-script-permission-denied scripts in profile.d are not run as root, they run as the user logging in when the shell is started.

Answer (score 0):

You have one issue that is not a problem that profile.d scripts are running as root.

In the other side, if inside your script is using the word "sudo" you may remove this because is not needed in profile.d .

If this script you will run it manually too, then you need to add sudo in cli before your script to work well in both scenarios.

In addition to all that has been said before, including the @serdroid answer, you may check my answer in this question, It basically describes how to avoid sudo authentication in certain scenarios.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/210395/28312

**Use it with responsability.**